# Some pins sometimes don't show up on MKMapView... WHY?

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

So I have the following code, that splits up the street,town,state,country,zip and makes an AddressAnnotation, a class I have extended from annotation.

Sometimes all of the pins show up on the map and sometimes it cannot find some of the places, although it is a collection of the exact same addresses every time.  Is there any reason why Google maps can find a place sometimes but not all the time?

Is it something in my code?

Thanks,
R

```
for (int i=0; i < [places count]-1; ++i) {

    NSArray *arrayPlace = [[places objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"***"];

    AddressAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:
                                        [self getLocationFromAddressString:
                                         [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                          @"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@",
                                          [arrayPlace objectAtIndex:3],
                                          [arrayPlace objectAtIndex:4],
                                          [arrayPlace objectAtIndex:5],
                                          [arrayPlace objectAtIndex:6],
                                          [arrayPlace objectAtIndex:7],
                                          [arrayPlace objectAtIndex:8]]]];




    [addAnnotation setWebsite:[arrayPlace objectAtIndex:2]];
    [addAnnotation setTitle:[arrayPlace objectAtIndex:0]];
    [addAnnotation setSubtitle:[arrayPlace objectAtIndex:1]];


    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
}
```

Comment: You should output the coordinate you get from the google API and see if it is the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be in the first line something like this?

```
for (int i=0; i < [places count]; i++) {
```

or better just:

```
for (NSArray *arrayPlace in places) {
```

Comment: nope, that'd mean you're trying to access [places objectAtIndex:1] on an array with only one object (which is at index 0) and that's not good. Mind you, the original poster's loop also misses the last element of the places array. In an array with one place i < [places count]-1 will return false when i = 0 and the loop won't go through. Unless there is something wrong with the last object in places the better loop statement would be for (int i=0; i < [places count]; ++i) {

Comment: yeah, I am purposefully avoiding the object in the last place ... for a probably not very good reason - but its intentional.

Comment: @Craig actually your solution was also wrong because you're not chcecking first element. ++i is a pre-incrementation so if there is one element in array you wouldn't get it.

Comment: I don't know why I typed ++i, I've never used that. You're right, it should be i++.

Comment: @Tobol, actually it turns out ++i works fine. That statement is executed stand alone at the end of each loop. Its value isn't copied in to anything so it doesn't matter if the increment happens before or after the value is used, so long as i goes up by one. You can check for yourself   for(int i=0; i< 10; ++i)
    {
        NSLog(@"Index %d",i);
    }
    That beings said, I'd still never use ++i in this situation because it looks strange.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I never used this but I always thought it gonna work the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the address strings you are generating. If they are always the same then look into getLocationFromAddressString and see if the coordinates it is returning are always the same. If not then that function has the problem. I've looked around for that function but Google just keeps bringing me back to StackOverflow. Is it your own function or have you used the one from this question? [MKMapView with address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383250/mkmapview-with-address)

Comment: I'll try printing out the coordinates - and yeah, I borrowed that function from the site you found.  Thanks - let you know how it goes!